# Replacing more than n consecutive values in Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, replace, multiple-columns, cumsum

Supposing I have the following DataFrame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5], "b" : [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7], "c" : [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3]})
```

And I wish to replace number 4's which repeat more than 10 times in a row, in any column (there could be hundreds of columns), with 10 4's and the remainder 5's.

**So for example, 12 consecutive 4's would be replaced with ten 4's and two 5's.**

How would I achieve this with Pandas?

I'd like to apply a lambda, but I don't know how to look back enough rows, and it would have to start from the end and move through forward, or it would break the sequence of values. Each lookup would have to look at the preceding 10 rows to see if they are all equal to 4, and if so, set the current value to 5.

No idea how to go about it though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
#column a is changed for 2 groups of 4
df = pd.DataFrame({
"a" : [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,7,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5], 
"b" : [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7], 
"c" : [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3]})
```

Solution counts consecutives 4 with reset if `NaN` created by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and then apply `boolean mask` to original `df` for replace `4` to `5` by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
a = df == 4
mask = a.cumsum()-a.cumsum().where(~a).ffill().fillna(0) > 10
df1 = df.mask(mask, 5)
```

```
print (df1)
    a  b  c
0   4  3  4
1   4  3  4
2   4  3  4
3   4  3  4
4   4  3  4
5   4  3  4
6   4  3  4
7   4  4  4
8   4  4  4
9   4  4  4
10  5  4  5
11  5  5  5
12  5  5  5
13  5  5  5
14  7  5  5
15  4  5  5
16  4  5  5
17  4  5  5
18  4  5  5
19  4  5  5
20  4  5  5
21  4  5  1
22  4  5  2
23  4  5  2
24  4  5  2
25  5  5  2
26  5  5  2
27  5  5  2
28  5  6  2
29  5  6  2
30  5  7  3
31  5  7  3
```

For better checking values is possible use `concat`:

```
print (pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1, keys=['orig','new']))
   orig       new      
      a  b  c   a  b  c
0     4  3  4   4  3  4
1     4  3  4   4  3  4
2     4  3  4   4  3  4
3     4  3  4   4  3  4
4     4  3  4   4  3  4
5     4  3  4   4  3  4
6     4  3  4   4  3  4
7     4  4  4   4  4  4
8     4  4  4   4  4  4
9     4  4  4   4  4  4
10    4  4  4   5  4  5
11    4  5  4   5  5  5
12    4  5  4   5  5  5
13    4  5  4   5  5  5
14    7  5  4   7  5  5
15    4  5  4   4  5  5
16    4  5  4   4  5  5
17    4  5  4   4  5  5
18    4  5  5   4  5  5
19    4  5  5   4  5  5
20    4  5  5   4  5  5
21    4  5  1   4  5  1
22    4  5  2   4  5  2
23    4  5  2   4  5  2
24    4  5  2   4  5  2
25    4  5  2   5  5  2
26    4  5  2   5  5  2
27    4  5  2   5  5  2
28    4  6  2   5  6  2
29    5  6  2   5  6  2
30    5  7  3   5  7  3
31    5  7  3   5  7  3
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: This is awesome. How does it work for any column- i.e. if I want to run it on columns a, b and c? Presumably I can stick it through a `for column in df.columns`?

Comment: It works in all columns nice, because all functions are implemented for dataframe. Check column `a` and `c`.

Comment: I add `concat` for better verify output, please check last edit.

Comment: This is unbelievable. How on earth do you become such a kung-fu Panda? I need to spend a good 30 minutes understanding how this works, but it works beautifully. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is many hours of coding. But this consecutives are really hard. Thank you for accepting!

Answer (score 3):

Remove all the 4s, fillna back with 4s using `limit=10` as argument, and remove the remaining NA with 5s. I find this method more explicit and reflecting more your intention:

```
df[df!=4].fillna(4, limit=10).fillna(5)
```

If needed cast the df back to integers with `astype(int)` at the end, as the intrusion of NAs will cast the dataframe into floats.

Comment: It works only if one group of `4` in column, check my sample  - second group of `4` in column `a` is replaced all values to 5

Comment: @jezrael BTW it's interesting I was misled by the argument docstring "If method is specified, this is the maximum number of consecutive
    NaN values to forward/backward fill. In other words, if there is
    a gap with more than this number of consecutive NaNs, it will only
    be partially filled. If method is not specified, this is the
    maximum number of entries along the entire axis where NaNs will be
    filled."

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5], "b" : [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7], "c" : [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3]})

def replacer(l,target_val=4,replace_val=5,repeat_max=10):
    counter = 0
    new_l = []
    for e in l:
        if e == target_val: counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 0

        if counter > repeat_max:
            new_l.append(replace_val)
        else:
            new_l.append(e)

    return new_l

df1 = df.apply(replacer)
```

Output:

```
    a  b  c
0   1  3  4
1   2  3  4
2   2  3  4
3   2  3  4
4   2  3  4
5   2  3  4
6   2  3  4
7   2  4  4
8   2  4  4
9   3  4  4
10  3  4  5
11  4  5  5
12  4  5  5
13  4  5  5
14  4  5  5
15  4  5  5
16  4  5  5
17  4  5  5
18  4  5  5
19  4  5  5
20  4  5  5
21  5  5  1
22  5  5  2
23  5  5  2
24  5  5  2
25  5  5  2
26  5  5  2
27  5  5  2
28  5  6  2
29  5  6  2
30  5  7  3
31  5  7  3
```